# Scala inner class generic bounds

Tags: scala, generics, inner-classes

I have external API setup similar to this:

```
abstract class PE {
  type Event

  abstract class C[R] {
    def reply(r: R)
    def persist[B <: Event](e: B)(callback: B => Unit): Persist
    def fail(error: Throwable): Persist
  }
  abstract class Persist {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I want to create a more functional-like wrapper based on scala's Try class. I came up with following code:

```
def tryPersist[P <: PE, E <: P#Event, R](c: PE#C[R], tryEvent: Try[E])(replyProducer: E => R): PE#Persist = {
    tryEvent match {
        case Success(event) =>
            c.persist(event)(_ => c.reply(replyProducer(event)))
        case Failure(exception) =>
            c.fail(exception)
    }
  }
```

However, that doesn't work because scala refuses to accept `PE#Persist` as `PE.this.Persist`. Is there something missing?

`inferred type arguments [E] do not conform to method persist's type parameter bounds [B <: _1.Event] c.persist(event)(_ => c.reply(replyProducer(event)))`

And in call place:

```
[error]  found   : MyPEImpl#Persist
[error]  required: MyPEImpl.this.Persist
[error]                     persistEvent(ctx, command.eventFor(state))(_.playerBet)
```

PS: In case anyony noticed, yes it's Lagom PersistentEntity's API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because `PE.this.Persist` is a subtype of `PE#Persist` so you are trying to pass a supertype where a specific subtype is required.

When types are nested like this, Scala creates a new nested type for each instance of the enclosing class. So an instance of `Persist` created using one instance of `PE` is not compatible with an instance of `Persist` created using a different instance of `PE`. The notation `PE#Persist` represents the supertype of all the different `PE.this.Persist` types.

Comment: So, how I can specify actual subtype of `PE#Persist`? Do I need to pass `pe: PE, c: pe.CommandContext[R]` somehow?

Comment: You can change `persist` to `def persist[B <: PE#Event]` but obviously that affects what `persist` can do.

Comment: That's external API, I can't change it @Tim